# Passing variable to input in pop-up window with jquery

Tags: jquery

Guyz, I've a weird situation: I need to pre-compile input field when visitor opens a pop-up window by clicking on the button.

See here: http://www.ageditalia.it/ in the header click on a little banner that says email and password. Pop-up will jump out. I need these password and email written on the banner to be inserted with jquery automatically.

I tried this:

```
$("a:.loginonthefly-open").click(function (event) {
    $("#auth_username").blur(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
        {
             $(this).val("haha");
        }
    });
    $("#auth_username").blur();
});
```

but field input gets cleared, I see my haha text for few seconds and than it disappears.

I don't understand what is going on,

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:
So far I got this, it works only on the second click when html is inserted in dom. Doesnt work on first click on fresh page load!

```
$("a:.loginonthefly-open").click(function (event) {
if($("#auth_username").val() == "") {
$("#auth_username").delay(200).queue(function(){
$("#auth_username").val("TEST");
});
}
});
```

How do I make it work on first load?

Obviously I need a better handler than click. any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need the blur? Have you tried just using the if statement on the click?

Comment: yes, I tried that too, effect is the same.

Comment: try get rid of onclick="toOpen(this, 58886) in your a tag. i dont know what it's purpose but perhaps it conflicted your jquery script

Comment: I cant get rid of any code, lets say everything is given. This is what makes this case hard. In simple html file on local I manage to do everything with jquery. Problem arises when I insert it into this cms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you hooking the code to the blur event? Try just doing it in the click function:

```
$("a:.loginonthefly-open").click(function (event) {
    if($("#auth_username").val() == "") {
        $("#auth_username").val("haha");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, with my code or urs the effect is same. HAHA gets removed for some weird reason :S

Comment: Something else must be clearing it — I tried to see it in action using the link you provided but I don't see "haha" at all!

Comment: Click few times without closing window. Now it is TEST that you will see :)

Comment: Clicking 'login' right? I can't get it to show the text in Chrome or Firefox!

Comment: No not login :) it's in the flash header. There is a blue box over a flash header with sliding images. The box has tires like olympic symbol on the right side. Click on that and box will open similar to what comes out when you click login.

btw, I managed to make it stick by delaying function. But first time page loads it still doesnt work.

Comment: You have some kind of ajax request running when you click on that area - the javascript runs on click as expected, but it's when the ajax completes that it gets cleared because you're reloading the form! You need to hook into the completion of the ajax request and fill in the form there.